# Numpy Dot Product of two 2-d arrays in numpy to get 3-d array

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

Sorry for the badly explained title. I am trying to parallelise a part of my code and got stuck on a dot product. I am looking for an efficient way of doing what the code below does, I'm sure there is a simple linear algebra solution but I'm very stuck:

```
puy = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)
puy2 = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

print puy, '\n'
print puy2.T

zz = np.zeros([4,2,3])

for i in range(4):
    zz[i,:,:] = np.dot(np.array([puy[:,i]]).T,
                np.array([puy2.T[i,:]]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum), which allows you to specify what you want to happen to the indices:

```
>>> np.einsum('ik,jk->kij', puy, puy2)
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 16, 32]],

       [[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 5, 25, 45]],

       [[ 4, 12, 20],
        [12, 36, 60]],

       [[ 9, 21, 33],
        [21, 49, 77]]])
>>> np.allclose(np.einsum('ik,jk->kij', puy, puy2), zz)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(puy[None,...]*puy2[:,None,:]).T
```